# How to act on callback function

Tags: angular, socket.io

I have a script that connects to server using WebSocket

```
export class AppComponent {

  connection_status = false;
  message = '';

  public connect() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:5001');
    this.socket.on('connected', this.connection_established);
  }
}
```

I would like to change the `connection_status` variable when `connected` message is received and save the content of the message to `message` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class AppComponent {

  connection_status = false;
  message = '';

  public connect() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:5001');
    this.socket.on('connected', this.connection_established.bind(this));
  }

  connection_established() {
    this.connection_established = true;
    this.message = 'connected';
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'connect' as event name instead of 'connected'? And i think this will fail because of the wrong context of `this` in the `connection_established` callback.

Comment: Edited to maintain the context of this in the callback. I have no idea whether the event is connect or connected; But to my understanding the question is regarding how to handle the callback

Comment: As @cyrix mentioned it doesn't work because the context of `this` has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extra binding simply **use the arrow function**, which has a lexical scoping to `this` context (means `this` will be preserved and accessible inside the arrow function body).

Also: it seems you're not using not WebSocket, but rather Socket.IO, which is built on top of WebSocket. According to [the official Socket.IO API documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/) you should use `socket.on("connect"` instead of `socket.on("connected"`.

Also you gave the same name to the boolean flag "connection_established" and to the method, which sets it to true. This would error out: `Duplicate identifier 'connection_established'.ts(2300)`

Also: it would be good idea to register event handlers before trying to connect (imagine connection is already done by the time you haven't yet register your `socket.on()` handler and only few milliseconds later you register it, but alas - a bit too late.

Here's how to "Do It The Right Way" (or in this case you could simply inline setting boolean flag inside arrow f-n instead of extra call for 2 code lines):

```
export class AppComponent {

  connection_status = false
  message = ''

  public connect() {
    socket.on('connect', () => this.set_connection_established())
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:5001')
  }

  set_connection_established() {
    this.connection_established = true
    this.message = 'connected'
  }
}
```

:)